# Directives with Isolated scope versions conflict

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my Angular app, i have a directive "editable". It written on Angular version 1.2.0-rc.2 and worked well, but when I upgraded framework to version 1.2.13 - directive broke. I checked capability with other versions, and was confused, because directive works only with three versions: 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0-rc.2 and 1.2.0-rc.3

In new versions this directive works only with two ugly edits:
1. directive's property "terminal" set to "true"
2. compile element in "link" function

Directive have simple logic:

1. show previously savedValue
2. click on button "EDIT" -> show input for new value
3. click on button "OK" to save value - > show new savedValue

Here is the code:

1. this version works: http://plnkr.co/edit/VHZVzk?p=preview
2. this version broken: http://plnkr.co/edit/NffdDj?p=preview
3. this version works with new insertions: http://plnkr.co/edit/7msiY0?p=preview

So, i have a questions:

1. Why it's all happens?
2. What differences between 1.2.0-rc* versions and other, that brake down directive.
3. Is there a way, better than compile directive and adding TERMINAL property to repair directive, because many other directives broken too?

Comment: Please post relevant code in your post to make your question self-contained without depending on 3rd-party service i.e. plunker

Comment: it's hard to tell what's going on (perhaps premature termination before the adjacent `ng-model`, tho they have the same priority level - 0 - which should prevent such effect), but it seems if you compile the `editable` directive, [all works fine](http://plnkr.co/edit/dWEt8ETp7LEQcaEhVhRD?p=preview). anyhow if you really want to dig into it, i suggest you take a look at the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: Eliran, if you look on compiled directive without property "terminal" setted to TRUE in your link, you will see, that value changes on both directives. It was a big problem for me =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First understanding

They actually changed something in the way the contents are compiled against a determined scope in case of an isolated scope.

### Breaking Changes from version 1.2.0

Please see their breaking changes brought with version 1.2.0 :

> - **$compile**:
>
>   - due to d0efd5ee, Child elements that are defined either in the application template or in some other directives template do not get the isolate scope. In theory, nobody should rely on this behavior, as it is very rare - in most cases the isolate directive has a template.
>   - due to 909cabd3, Directives without isolate scope do not get the isolate scope from an isolate directive on the same element. If your code depends on this behavior (non-isolate directive needs to access state from within the isolate scope), change the isolate directive to use scope locals to pass these explicitly.

In your specific case, your edit button cannot access the properties and methods you implemented on the isolated scope. You were able to do that temporarily in those "rc" versions.

### Fast solution

Don't use isolated scope for your directive.

### Deeper solution

You are actually doing something quite weird. You create an isolated scope to get `ngModel` binded to the scope used by your directive.

But, working with the `ngModel` directive doesn't work that way. You have to require the `ngModelController` instance added by the `ngModel` directive, using a directive property called `require`, that you will fill with the name of the directive your are requiring the controller of, that is to say "ngModel".
Then the forth argument of your `link` function will refer to the `ngModelController` instance which is quite well documented on the Angular documentation.

So ! :

- don't use isolated scope when you don't need it
- remember isolated scope is not directly accessible on the element itself anymore, except using the `$$childHead` property of course ... but you should not do that !