# AngularJS : Scope not shared across directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have 2 directives on the same tag, `<settings>` and `<modal>`. `settings` provides a template, while `modal` creates an isolated scope:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lperrin/eTGJ7/)

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('settings', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        template: '<div>SETTINGS</div>',

        link: function (scope) {
            console.log('settings', scope.$id);
        }
    };
});

app.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        scope: {},

        link: function (scope) {
            console.log('modal', scope.$id);
        }
    };
});
```

However, they do not end up sharing the same scope, as shown by the logs:

```
<settings modal="settings"></settings>

settings 002
modal 003
```

Why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till version 1.2.0rc3, sibling directives were sharing the same isolated scope if created.

As of version 1.2.0, you cannot (and shouldn't) access the isolated scope from outside the contents compiled against this isolated scope. You shouldn't because you are creating a hidden relation between both directives. Better use directive's controller requirement via the `require` property, or share informations through injected services if singleton pattern can be applied to your use case.

It is finally deeply related to this other question about [Directives with Isolated scope versions conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309782/directives-with-isolated-scope-versions-conflict/22312396#22312396)

Answer (score 1):

`scope: {}` option always creates an isolated scope for the directive, it doesn't care about other directives

Comment: OK, but can I somehow get the 2 directives to share the same (isolated) scope ? They can't both create an isolated scope.

Comment: you can make the non-isolated directive ember into the isolated one, or create an isolated wrapper directive and then keep both of them non-isolated... I don't think it's a good idea to mix non-isolated/isolated directives as one element

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, possibly by forcing the isolating directive to transclude the non-isolated one, but I guess I have no choice…

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        scope: false,

        link: function (scope) {
            console.log('modal', scope.$id);
        }
    };
});
```

scope: false will not create a new isolated scope. I you want to make two directives work between them use require a controller on the directive that way you can share data between them.