# invisible properties of isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
})

myApp.directive('dir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
      scope:{
          name:"="
      },
      controller: function($scope) {},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
           scope.insider="FFFF"
    }
  }

});
```

While rendering the below html, why is 'insider' shown as null.

What is the ideal way of storing directive related variables when isolated scope is used?
Why are the properties not being rendered correctly in template??

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/2449/)

```
//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

<div ng-app="myApp"><div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
    <dir name='name'>{{insider}}{{name}}</dir>
</div></div>
```

Comment: I think insider is empty because your directive is not transcluded, so basically all of its content gets compiled within the parent scope... it would work the same if you delete `name:"="`, so the isolated scope is actually created, but since you don't transclude the content nor define directive's template, it won't be used anywhere

Comment: if you create a template for the isolated scope, it works - take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/2456/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this breaking change in the change log of version 1.2.0:

> due to d0efd5ee, Child elements that are defined either in the application template or in some other directives template do not get the isolate scope. In theory, nobody should rely on this behavior, as it is very rare - in most cases the isolate directive has a template.

Your question is actually deeply related to this question about [Directives with Isolated scope versions conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309782/directives-with-isolated-scope-versions-conflict/22312396#22312396)

So if you create a template, it all works fine !

*Moreover...*

As a debug-like way to inspect scopes, you will actually be able to read the `insider` property using this interpolation string:

```
{{$$childHead.insider}}{{name}}
```

But don't do that in your final implementation !